# Calculate mortgage loan amount given monthly maximum payment

Tags: php, math, calculator, finance

NOTE: I tried using Math Stack Exchange with no luck. Hoping a fellow programmer can help.

I am trying to determine a mortgage loan amount, and have successfully done so using the following formula:

```
monthlyPayment = monthlyPayment - homeownersInsurance - mortgageInsurance

loanAmount = ( monthlyPayment * ( 1 - ( ( 1 + interestRate ) ^ -loanTerm ) ) ) / interestRate
```

ASSUME: Buyer puts down nothing for a down payment, and that monthlyPayment, homeownersInsurance, mortgageInsurance, interestRate and loanTerm are known values.

However, how do I factor in propertyTaxes which is dependent on the loanAmount?

I thought I would perform the above calculation, and then do this:

```
propertyTaxes = ( propertyTaxes * loanAmount ) / 12;

monthlyPayment = monthlyPayment - propertyTaxes;

    loanAmount = ( monthlyPayment * ( 1 - ( ( 1 + interestRate ) ^ -loanTerm ) ) ) / interestRate
```

But that isn't accurate.

Comment: Could you give us an example with actual numbers?

Comment: Property taxes are dependent on the city's valuation of the house, not the loan amount.

Comment: Are you trying to figure out how much left to pay on an existing loan? Then your loanAmount formula should be all you need. 

If you are trying to figure out what you can borrow, it really depends on where you live. For example, where I am, it cant go over 35% personal debt per year based on total household income before taxes. So if you want that, you will need to talk with a finance expert or else you'll never be accurate. Some banks also have different requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The property tax is dependent on the county tax assessor--
Often, not always but a decent rule of thumb, this is closely tracked to the purchase price of the home. 
(example: principal on the loan if they put $0 down payment (unlikely case). Or, say they put 20% down, and the loan principal is 80,000, then $100,000 is the purchase price * .0125 property tax (depending on the county))

(Many states property tax per year is ~ .0125.)
So, you could do: 
propertyTax = purchasePrice * .0125